# Date time changed in date = date

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, datetime

This is my code

> model.dateOfBirth is date time from `datepicker`  but it is `date` not `string`
>
> In addition current culture is `fa-IR`

```
dateOfBirth = model.dateOfBirth.Value;
//model.dateOfBirth.Value = {13/05/1367 12:00:00 ق.ظ} tick = 627222528000000000
//dateOfBirth = {04/08/1988 12:00:00 ق.ظ} (it is true in text but not in value) tick!!! = 823262400000000000
```

> question updated

Why thay are not equal?

`model.dateOfBirth.Value.Tick != dateOfBirth.Value.Tick`

> 627222528000000000 = 1988-08-04​T00:00:00.000Z
>
> 823262400000000000 = 2609-10-26​T00:00:00.000Z

The question is why date is changed by `=` expertion ?

#### I can fix the problem but the question is why value changed?

I fixed this by:

```
 dateOfBirth = new DateTime(model.dateOfBirth.Value.Ticks);
```

Comment: what do you mean by `date is changed by = expertion` ? what else do you expect?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary the tick is changed in `=` expersion

Comment: is that a DateTimePicker? your question is still unclear. Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary both of them are date time Why is it important date time picker or not?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary updated. Why this is unclear? I want to set another date Time variable with current date time variable why the value changed during set?

Comment: I'm really confused with your question. by the way check if both datetimes have same time zone, are both UTC? GMT? if not that's why they conflict because the time calculated from given tick will be different

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem maybe in Culture (current thread culture is `fa-IR`) or .net bug for avoid future problem I used `Tick` value instead of `=` and create new date by `Tick` value of `model.dateOfBirth.Value.Ticks` therefore my new `dateOfBirth` time value have exact tick value as `model.dateOfBirth.Value.Ticks` and now are same date value.

Code:

```
dateOfBirth = new DateTime(model.dateOfBirth.Value.Ticks);
```

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.